# How do I add name property to a DOM input checkbox object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to add a name to a DOM input object so that I can save it into my database but I can't figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a Checkbox.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code only makes dynamic checkboxes but I don't know how to add a name to it to send it via $_POST['name'];

Comment: `x.name = 'nameofcheckbox'`

Answer (score 0):

**set attribute name**

```
 function myFunction() {
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        x.setAttribute("name", "checkbox_name");
        document.body.appendChild(x);
    }
```

> you need to add input element in form element

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.name` DOM element property:

```
x.name = 'myCheckbox';
```

Moreover, you can set `type` using `.type` property:

```js
var x = document.createElement("input");
x.type = 'checkbox';
x.name = 'myCheckbox';
document.body.appendChild(x);

// Just for demonstration:
document.getElementById('result').innerText = x.outerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

If you ever have any questions regarding DOM element properties, you can refer to [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element).

As you have mentionted jQuery in question tags, I will also provide a jQuery approach:

```
$("<input/>").attr({'name': 'myCheckbox', 'type': 'checkbox').appendTo('body');
```